# $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent, have exponential distributions with parameter $\alpha$. Find pdf and cdf of $|\xi - \eta|$: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, random-variables

Exercise:

> Random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent, and both have
> exponential distributions with same parameter $\alpha$. Find pdf and
> cdf of random variable $|\xi - \eta|.$

pdf of $\xi$ = pdf of $\eta$ = $p(y) = $

\begin{equation*}
  =\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      & \alpha e^{-\alpha y}, \ y \geq 0\\
      & 0, \ y<0.
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

My solution:

first find cdf, then obtain pdf by taking a derivative of cdf.

$$
F_{|\xi-\eta|}(t) = P(|\xi-\eta|<t) = \int_{0}^{t} p(y) \int_{0}^{t-y} p(x) \,dx \,dy =
\int_{0}^{t} \alpha e^{-\alpha y} \int_{0}^{t-y} \alpha e^{-\alpha x} \,dx \,dy =
\int_{0}^{t} \alpha e^{-\alpha y} \alpha \left( -\frac{1}{\alpha} e^{-\alpha x} \bigg|^{t-y}_0 \right) \,dy 
$$

$$
= \int_{0}^{t} \alpha e^{-\alpha y} \left( 1-e^{\alpha y - \alpha t} \right) \,dy  =
\alpha \int_{0}^{t}  e^{-\alpha y} -e^{- \alpha t}  \,dy =
\alpha \int_{0}^{t}  e^{-\alpha y} \,dy - \alpha \int_{0}^{t} e^{- \alpha t}  \,dy = 
\alpha \left( -\frac{1}{\alpha} e^{-\alpha y} \right) \bigg|^t_0 - \alpha e^{-\alpha t}t  
$$

$$
= - \left(  e^{-\alpha t} - 1 \right)  - \alpha e^{-\alpha t}t = 1 - e^{-\alpha t} - \alpha e^{-\alpha t}t. 
$$

For pdf of $|\xi - \eta|,$ we differentiate $1 - e^{-\alpha t} - \alpha e^{-\alpha t}t$:

$$
p_{|\xi - \eta|}(t) = \alpha e^{-\alpha t} + \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha t} t - \alpha e^{-\alpha t} = \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha t} t, \ t \geq 0.
$$
(For $t<0$, it's zero).

The textbook answer is $p_{|\xi - \eta|}(t) = p(t),$ i.e. $|\xi - \eta|$ has the same exponential distribution as $\xi$ and $\eta$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation goes awry almost immediately because your limits of integration cannot possibly be correct.  To see why, notice that whenever $\xi = \eta$, then $|\xi - \eta| = 0 \le t$ for any $t \ge 0$.  This includes values where $\xi$ and $\eta$ exceed $t$, because as long as they are sufficiently close together in value, their absolute difference will not exceed $t$.

But your limits of integration correspond to a triangular region with vertices $(0,0), (t,0), (0,t)$, and as such cannot possibly be correct.  This underlines the importance of using different ways to check the reasonableness of your work.

When we say $|\xi - \eta| \le t$, this really means that the values of $\xi$ and $\eta$, when plotted in the Cartesian coordinate plane, lie in an infinite diagonal strip that is symmetric about the line $\xi = \eta$, and whose width is some function of $t$.  Since $\xi$ and $\eta$ are nonnegative, this in turn would require us to split up the region of integration into two parts.  So instead, it is easier to use the complementary approach; i.e.,

$$\Pr[|\xi - \eta| \le t] = 1 - \Pr[|\xi - \eta| > t] = 1 - 2 \Pr[\xi - \eta > t],$$

where in the last equality we have exploited the IID property of $\xi$ and $\eta$ which implies that their joint density is symmetric about the aforementioned line $\xi = \eta$.

Now our integration may proceed easily:

$$\begin{align}
\Pr[\xi - \eta > t]
&= \Pr[\xi > \eta + t] \\
&= \int_{\eta = 0}^\infty \int_{\xi = \eta + t}^\infty \alpha e^{-\alpha \xi} \alpha e^{-\alpha \eta} \, d \xi \, d \eta \\
&= \int_{\eta = 0}^\infty \alpha e^{-\alpha \eta} e^{-\alpha (\eta + t)} \, d \eta \\
&= \int_{\eta = 0}^\infty \alpha e^{-\alpha t} e^{-2 \alpha \eta} \, d \eta \\
&= \frac{e^{-\alpha t}}{2}.
\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$\Pr[|\xi - \eta| \le t] = 1 - e^{-\alpha t},$$
from which it is now obvious that $|\xi - \eta|$ is itself exponentially distributed with the same rate $\alpha$ as $\xi$ and $\eta$.

Answer (score 1):

For $t\geqslant0$ we have
$$
\{|\xi-\eta|\leqslant t\} = \{-t\leqslant \xi-\eta\leqslant t\} = \{\xi-\eta\leqslant t\}\setminus\{\xi-\eta\leqslant-t\}.
$$
We then compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(|\xi-\eta|\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(\xi-\eta\leqslant t) - \mathbb P(\xi-\eta\leqslant -t)\\
&= \mathbb P(\xi\leqslant\eta+t)-\mathbb P(\xi\leqslant\eta-t)\\
&= \int_0^\infty\int_0^{y+t} \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha(x+y))}\ \mathsf dx \mathsf dy - \int_t^\infty\int_0^{y-t} \alpha^2 e^{-\alpha(x+y))}\ \mathsf dx \mathsf dy\\
&= 1-\frac12 e^{-\alpha t} - \left(\frac12 e^{-\alpha t}\right)\\
&=1- e^{-\alpha t},
\end{align}
whence $|\xi-\eta|\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\alpha)$.

Comment: Is this legal to have $y$ in both outer and inner integrals $\int_y^\infty\int_0^{y-t}$ ?

Comment: @fragileradius Ah, seems I made a typo. The lower bound should be $t$, since $\xi$ and $\eta$ are nonnegative.